# Dropdown list to a model in MVC which is a List<>

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have a model, which is a List of some objects. Every object, has a "description" filed. Now, I want a dropdown list with all the descriptions, that inside this list.

```
    public ActionResult PopPage(string line)
    {
        List<Campaign> CampaignList = new List<Campaign>();
        SetLogFiles();            
        try
        {
            ViewBag.CLID = line;
            CampaignList = DBAccess.GetCampaigns();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.WriteError(ex);
        }

        return View("LineStatePopUp",CampaignList);

    }
```

In the top of the view:

```
@model List<ClickServer.Models.Campaign>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the list of campaigns as model to your view. That's fine. But how are you going to get the value that the user would select? For that you should have a property at you server side binded to the selected item at client-side.

I would suggest using a ViewModel which would have the list of campaigns as collection of SelectListItem (which would be populated in the controller) and another property for the selected item and then instead of passing the list of campaigns directly to your view you should pass the new viewModel and bind accordingly.

ViewModel

```
public class CampaignsViewModel
{
    public int SelectedCampaignId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Campaigns{ get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model CampaignsViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCampaignId , Model.Campaigns)
```